# Could not change profile image of my Android app while automating with Appium

Tags: java, android, mobile, ui-automation, appium

[image]

I could not select an image from the gallery app. I am automating my Android app using Appium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I have launch Android photo gallery using following code from a activity.

   ```
   Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   intent.setType("image/*");
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Test code can have following implementation.

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.android.gallery:id/grid")));
    driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
    HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    map.put("x", 0.3);
    map.put("y", 0.3);
    (driver).executeScript("mobile: tap", map);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

how are you implementing it? You can use UIAutomator to find out the xPATH or IDs to reach to the image. you can also use "tap" to select a particular image. post your existing code,

Comment: I could not get any xPATH or IDs while inspecting gallery screen for image.

Comment: I used android's own UIAutomator to fetch the Ids. I got com.android.gallery:id/grid for the complete grid view which contains images but ids or internal structure of this view is not disclosed. Hence I saw its x and y co-ordinate and tentatively selected 0.3 as X and Y as image was present there. You will need to make sure image is present or else handle it in the code.